# When to avoid surface reconstruction

Tags: algorithm, 3d, computational-geometry, point-clouds

Suppose that you have a number of large  point clouds and you want to observe whether they contain any valuable information or meaningful surfaces. To decrease the cost of surface reconstruction, you may ignore some point clouds with specific distribution, for instance, random distribution. How do you pick the point clouds with meaningful point orders and which ones do you avoid to reconstruct?

Comment: Maybe this question belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am looking for the theoretical stand views. I am not interested in the efficiency of the pseudo-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Pick several locations and explore [covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) there. If the surface is well approximated by a plane in the neighbourhood, one of eigen values of the matrix will very small. The size of the neighbourhood used for analysis depends on smoothness of the surface.
2. Split the space into voxel grid. Count voxels containing at least one point. Then half size of voxels and count again. After several such measurements you will be able to approximate [dependency of voxel number on voxel size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension). For surface-like distribution it should be number~(1/size)^2, for uniform distribution around volume it will be closer to (1/size)^3.

Comment: thank you for your insights. My reputation is too low to vote up your answer.

Comment: Can you give me references for (1) and (2).

Comment: Suppose I have a number of points randomly distributed in a sphere of radius r (for instance, the case of complete spatial randomness). Can I reconstruct meaningful surfaces here? what is the relation between the points distribution and difficulty of surface reconstruction?

Comment: @Jolfaei, regarding references: the links I gave are the closest links I have, it's only an application of the referenced concepts

Comment: @Jolfaei, regarding points on sphere: I don't know how you reconstruct surfaces, in my answer I assumed that if there is a smooth enough surface and there is enough points sampled on it, it's possible to reconstruct it. If you have different restrictions on points set, it makes sense to mention them in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think you have partially answered my question. For instance, in your first suggestion, you did not mention any thing about the distribution of vertices (which I asked in the question). I am interested to see under what distribution of vertices or combination of normals we cannot reconstruct smooth surfaces.